# How can I read attribute of object in Ruby/Rails by string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is the following code:

```
def image_tag_src(subject, type)
    (subject.errors.present? || subject[type].blank?) ? "" : subject[type].url
end
```

I use it as `image_tag_src(@tire, "icon")`; tire's attribute 'icon' is not empty, but the function always returns "". What's the trouble? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any other `errors`? And also **``icon is not empty``** means it holds a **`non-empty`** value?

Comment: No, there are no errors. Yes, it holds non-empty value.

Comment: put debugger inside the `method image_tag_src` and inspect the value of subject and check `subject[type]` is blank or not.

Comment: Change this `subject[type].url` to a hard coded value, say `"/some/url"` and check if you are getting it or an empty String.

Answer (score 1):

I had a conflict issue by using 'type' within my model. Changing that to a different name solved my issue of displaying it on my view.